# Не могу присвоить класс объекту

Tags: javascript

```
const iconMenu = document.querySelector('.header__burger');
if (iconMenu) {
    const menuBody = document.querySelector('.header__menu');
    iconMenu.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        iconMenu.classList.toggle('._active');
        menuBody.classList.toggle('._active');
    })
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   --- ознакомьтесь пожалуйста

Comment: В методах classList используются имена классов, а не селекторы. Так что точка там лишняя.